# How can we get access token from MSAL to call subscription API

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-ad-msal

Problem that I was facing that I want to call subscription API in angular using MSAL Graph API's but I can't so I just want to know that how to implement it and how can i get the User access token in Angular using graph API's

```
async createSubscription(subscription:any) {
    const accessToken = await this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes: ['user.read', 'openid', 'profile','offline_access'],
    });

    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
     console.log({accessToken})
    this.http.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions', subscription, { headers }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
```

Comment: For which resource (like user, message, etc.) do you want to create a subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample from SPA authentication documentation using the angular to acquire a token:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http"; // Import 

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';

import { MsalModule, MsalRedirectComponent, MsalGuard, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular'; // Import MsalInterceptor
import { InteractionType, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot( new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'Enter_the_Application_Id_Here',
        authority: 'Enter_the_Cloud_Instance_Id_Here/Enter_the_Tenant_Info_Here',
        redirectUri: 'Enter_the_Redirect_Uri_Here',
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      }
    }), {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read']
        }
    }, {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([ 
          ['Enter_the_Graph_Endpoint_Here/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
      ])
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    MsalGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code#acquire-a-token

Hope this helps.